# Reading Text File (Separating, Sorting, Find the Between Numbers With ArrayList)

Tags: java, sorting, text, arraylist

I'm really shy to say this problem. Because i couldn't understand how to do it. I've a text file. In this text file there is a 1 million numbers. These are between 0 to 999 and every line contains a number. I have to separate these numbers with (\n), that means every line will contains one integer number. Then i have to sort these. After sorting i will take 2 inputs from user. Then i have to find and write numbers to a new text file between these inputs in the first text file.

I know most people will say "we're not fool. You don't know anything, this site is not like this." That's right, but i have to do this. I just want to know how can i do this. Which methods or strategies do i need? Because i've found similar things in here but i don't know are these true with my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading the file I suggest you use this, will make your task quite simple.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

For sorting, look at this class, it has a `sort` method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

For converting String values (which you read from the file)
to int or Integer values use this class, it has `parseInt` method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: I'm still reading your sources. Thanks a lot it will help a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using Java 8:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Pair input = readInput();
    final Path sourceFile = Paths.get("path", "to", "input", "file");
    final Path destFile = Paths.get("path", "to", "output", "file");
    final IntStream parsed = Files.lines(sourceFile).
            mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).
            filter(i -> i >= input.getLow() && i <= input.getHigh()).
            parallel().
            sorted();
    try (final PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(destFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        parsed.forEach(outputFile::println);
    }
}

private static Pair readInput() {
    final Console console = System.console();
    final String low = console.readLine("Please enter the start number (inclusive): ");
    final String high = console.readLine("Please enter the end number (inclusive): ");
    return new Pair(Integer.parseInt(low), Integer.parseInt(high));
}

private static final class Pair {
    private final int low;
    private final int high;

    private Pair(int low, int high) {
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }

    public int getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public int getLow() {
        return low;
    }
}
```

The `readInput()` method uses a [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) to read the high and low values into a class `Pair` that holds the user input.

The `main` method calls `readInput()` then reads lines from the input file, filters out numbers that are lower than `low` and higher than `high` and parallel sorts the resultant output.

Once we have the pipeline setup, we then call `forEach` on it and write the value to the output file.

Comment: @Calaquessir well then I suppose you have some reading to do.

Answer (score -1):

For sorting numbers you can use counting sort algorithm: you have numbers of limited range, from 0 to 999. So, you can count how many times each number occurred in input file:

```
int[] count = new int[1000];
//depending of scope, maybe you need to fill array with zeroes

...
int number = ...;//read number from file;
count[number]++;
```

Now, in order to output it as sorted, you just need two loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; ++j) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I wrote this just to make sure idea is clear, although your task doesn't require to output them all. Now, let's imagine you read these two numbers;

```
int start, finish = 0; //value read from input
```

We gonna modify the loops above like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; ++j) {
        if ((counter >= start) && (counter < finish)) {//or maybe <=, depending on what exactly do you need
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter > finish) { //we finished, further iterations are waste of CPU time
            break(2);
        }  
    }
}
```

This method is not optimal, but easy to understand and implement. For more fast solutions, you may want to get rid of inner loop, replacing it with logic to add `count[i]` to `counter` at once and detecting moment when we need to start output.

Comment: I don't know why you got -1. I can use these algorithms on my work. Thanks for your attention too.